# PsExec :: Access Denied

Tags: windows, remote-desktop-services, remote-access, pstools

I am working on PsExec but i get error as "Access Denied "
Firewall is disabled on both machine. Ports are also open at both machine.

```
C:\PSTOOLS>PsExec \\192.168.1.232 -u Administrator "c:\test\sample.bat Shailesh"

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Password:

Couldn't access 192.168.1.232:
Access is denied.
```

Comment: Did you omit the second \ in \\192.168.1.232 in the command line too? the command should be `psexec \\192.168.1.232 -u administrator "c:\test\sample.bat Shailesh"`

Comment: Also, when you say the firewall is disabled, do you mean "the service is disabled" or "the firewall is passing all traffic"?

Comment: Firewall service is disabled. Also have given command as psexec \\192.168.1.232 -u administrator "c:\test\sample.bat Shailesh" but its not working.

Comment: Disabling the firewall service can cause all sorts of problems, since windows effectively doesn't know what to do so it just blocks the traffic. Try enabling the firewall service but switching the firewall into passive mode (basically turn it off).

Comment: and what exactly makes you think firewalls have anything to do with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right password for Administrator?  Also, is this a local account or a domain account?

Comment: @KatherineVillyard think you've hit the nail on the head in this case.

Comment: @John Firewall service is up and running but i turned it off.

Comment: @Katherine Yes i have right password for Administrator. Its a local account.

Answer (score 2):

If this is not related to the firewall, which it sounds like it's not, and you definitely have the correct admin password for the remote machine, then check the following:

- File and Print Sharing is enabled on the remote (and possibly local) machine.
- The `admin$` share of the remote machine exists and is accessible.

The following article is quite a lengthy explanation of how psexec can work, by Mark Russinovich (creator of the sysinternals suite).

Comment: File and Print Sharing service and Admin$ share is enabled on the remote machine. But i do not have DC Configured in my premises for windows systems.

Comment: This should work regardless of whether or not there is a DC available, since you are using a local administrator account.